# Find generating function of given problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

please help me to find the generating function of this problem 
 $a_k = ( k + 1) for  k=0,1,2,3,...$

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)=\sum_{k\ge 0}(k+1)x^k=\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}x^k\right)'=\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)'= {\rm etc}.$$

Comment: @Mårten W : Thank you very much.